# Are there any side effects if am supposed to draw a card but have no cards to draw?

Tags: untagged

I was playing Hero Realms this weekend with a friend. He ended having a combo that made him able to virtually draw endless cards.

He was able to draw his full deck within one turn, shuffle his discard pile drawing that one empty, too and he would have still been able to draw additional cards, but his whole deck was being played out in this one turn, until there were neither cards left in his deck, nor in his discard pile.

We agreed if there are no cards left, he can't draw any cards anymore.

Do the rules state any side effect about drawing cards, if there are no cards to draw left and the discard pile being empty as well?

Answer (score 3):

Never played the game but i'm very familiar with Star Realms.

Your question was asked [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1916499/drawing-empty-deck-no-discard-pile) on BGG.  No official source chipped in but its seems common sense that if you are unable to do something nothing happens.  Just do as much as you can on the cards.

When I play Star Realms on the app and I want to draw cards and the draw and discard are empty then there is just no effect.

Comment: In that BGG thread, note that Ian Taylor (IanWWG) is an official source. Ian Taylor is the Director of Organized Play for White Wizard Games.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that.  I thought WWG might indicate that but when I checked the name it didn't match that of the designers.  I didn't think to check publishers.  Thanks for correction.